# Facebook Graph Search Complex Query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, xmlhttprequest, social-networking

I'm trying to dig into Facebook search api,
i'm using an HttpRequest:
 https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=key
And this works fine.
Now i;m trying to do a bit more complex query something like: People who like Somthing and live in France...
does any one have any idea how to build such query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For more complex queries, FQL might be a more suitable option. 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

To get started, test your queries with the Graph API Explorer (there is an option to also test FQL Queries!):
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer